# sql - group by parts of a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using sql to pull together a table like this:

```
person         flavour                                purchase
andy         likes-orange_hates-vanilla                  $5
george       likes-orange_hates-icecream                 $5
gena         likes-vanilla_hates-bourban                 $2
gena         likes-vanilla_hates-bourban                 $4
```

Is it possible to go from that to:

```
                total
likes-orange     $10
likes-vanilla    $6
```

even better would be

```
              total      av. purchase size     av. purchases per person    total people
likes-orange    $10                $5                   1                        2
likes-vanilla   $6                 $3                   2                        1
```

I just have access to a phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is it the source table or result of your query?

Comment: Normalize your database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
select substring_index(flavor,'_',1), sum(purchase) from table group by 1
```

Comment: Why not GROUP BY substring_index(flavor,'_',1)?

Comment: Why bother with redundancy (and more chance for error) when SQL syntax allows you to refer to the column by position?

Comment: So this is column position... Nice. Is this only MySQL functionality, or its available in another databases (eg. MSSQL, Sybase, Oracle)?

Comment: `SELECT substring_index(flavor,'_',1) AS groupByMe, sum(purchase) AS sumOfPurchases FROM table GROUP BY groupByMe` is probably more transportable, aliasing the grouped row

Comment: @Simonatmso.net unfortunately, not all databases (i.e. Oracle) support this.

Comment: @Kamil: `order by column index` is standard SQL

Comment: Fair enough :)  Just as well this one's tagged as MySQL.  Is it that Oracle doesn't support aliasing, or that it doesn't support grouping by an alias?

Comment: The latter - grouping by alias

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2005+

Following can be used :

```
Select Tbl1.Email, Count(1) FROM (
    Select substring(EmailAdd,CHARINDEX('@',EmailAdd),Len(EmailAdd)-CHARINDEX('@',EmailAdd)) as 'Email'
    from TableName 
) Tbl1 Group By Tbl1.Email
```